# how to place output data-frame in D2 instead of A1 in google sheets with gspread python

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, gspread

```
# accessing workbook
wb = gc.open_by_url('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LcFa9PDSjaL-Po47okWzLaUC4QUdtRSXzrgslTo6V7E/edit#gid=0')

# creating new worksheet
worksheet = wb.add_worksheet(title="A_worksheet", rows="100", cols="20")

# print df in new worksheet
sh = wb.worksheet('A_worksheet')
set_with_dataframe(sh, df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just went through the source code for `set_with_dataframe`. You can pass `row` and `col` as a parameter, the default is 1 and hence where it writes. Try passing appropriate values and check.

```
def set_with_dataframe(worksheet,
                       dataframe,
                       row=1,
                       col=1,
                       include_index=False,
                       include_column_header=True,
                       resize=False,
                       allow_formulas=True):
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks its working, actually i was using only row & column parameter

Comment: Happy to hear that it is working. If you found the answer helpful consider accepting the answer by clicking on the tick on the side of the answer.